Jinja2: how to create dict where values are variables?
I'm trying to create a list of dicts, where each dict item is like this: {"domain": "example.com", "score": 0.42}. The problem is that Jinja2 is not evaluating the variables and instead creating a dict like this: {'domain': '{{ event["domain"]["name"] }}', 'score': '{{ int(event["additional"]["Score"]) }}'}.
I need to create that temp findings list of dicts because the original score value is a string, so the sort() would not work as expected.
How to make Jinja evaluate the variable before creating the dict?
{% set findings = [] %}
{% for event in input_json["events"] %}
    {% set updated_event = ({
        "domain": '{{ event["domain"]["name"] }}',
        "score": '{{ int(event["additional"]["Score"]) }}'
    }) %}

    {% set _ = findings.append(updated_event) %}
{% endfor %}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Domain</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in findings | sort(reverse=True, attribute="score") %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item["domain"] }}</td>
            <td>{{ item["score"] }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>


"domain": event["domain"]["name"],, you are in a Jinja block already (even if it is a statement one and not an expression one), so, your variables are templated already.
